# How to start OAuth2.0 server in localhost using Yii2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am newbie on OAuth2.0 and YII2. I am trying to setup OAuth using [Filsh Library](https://github.com/Filsh/yii2-oauth2-server). Everything setup correctly according to the documentation. But while trying to hit the url it throws me 404 page not found. Please help me where i am wrong and how to start the server.

**Project File Structure**

[image: Project File Structure]

**`Step 1: Composer.json`**

```
  "filsh/yii2-oauth2-server": "~2.0"
```

**`Step 2: module`**

```
'oauth2' => [
        'class' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\Module',
        'tokenParamName' => 'access_token',
        'tokenAccessLifetime' => 3600 * 24,
        'storageMap' => [
            'user_credentials' => 'api\models\Users',
        ],
        'grantTypes' => [
            'user_credentials' => [
                'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials',
            ],
            'refresh_token' => [
                'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\RefreshToken',
                'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

**`Step 3: Url`**

```
 'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'POST oauth2/<action:\w+>' => 'oauth2/rest/<action>',
        ],
```

**`Step 4: AuthController`**

```
class AuthController extends ActiveController
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
            'authenticator' => [
                'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
                'authMethods' => [
                    ['class' => HttpBearerAuth::className()],
                    ['class' => QueryParamAuth::className(), 'tokenParam' => 'access_token'],
                ]
            ],
            'exceptionFilter' => [
                'class' => ErrorToExceptionFilter::className()
            ],
        ]);
    }

}
```

**`Step 5: Implement IdentityInterface, UserCredentialsInterface`**

```
   class Users extends api\models\Users implements \OAuth2\Storage\UserCredentialsInterface, IdentityInterface
    { 

    }
```

While trying to hit  `http://192.168.100.3/dashboard/oauth2/token` 
It throws the message

```
404 Not Found http://192.168.100.3/dashboard/oauth2/token
```

Comment: what is `dashboard` in the url `http://192.168.100.3/dashboard/oauth2/token `? is it the application root or `module` name? should'nt it be `http://192.168.100.3/oauth2/token`

Comment: dashboard is the application root.
->dashboard
   ->api

Comment: okay , and by `->dashboard ->api` you mean  you have the `api` app like a separate `frontend` and `backend` app if i am not getting wrong and your `AuthController` is inside the `api/controllers` app

Comment: Yes, the Authcontroller class is inside the api folder. I have upload the picture of my project structure, please look at up.

Comment: yeah i just saw after posting the message, and how do you access the `frontend` app if you have to what does the path looks like, and why are you using the `IP` why not using the virtual host ? or do you have a virtual host defined for the frontend ?

Comment: I am trying it with my mobile device so i kept IP address.
That Ip adress can be replaced by localhost.
To access frontend 
http://localhost/dashboard/frontend/web/index.php
To access backend
http://localhost/dashboard/backend/web/index.php
To access api
http://localhost/celebrity-dashboard/api/web/v1/<controller>

Comment: then you should send request to `http://192.168.100.3/api/oauth2/token` , it should work.

Comment: application folder(dashboard) should be ignore or should be write on URL. Trying with both gave 404 not found message.

Comment: sorry? did you said that you are trying to access it via mobile ? are you able to access the frontend via mobile?

Comment: Actually i am developing Api for Android App. And try to implement OAuth. All API URL work perfectly through my mobile except the OAuth url. I am confused where i have made mistake on Implementing OAUTH. I have completely followed the instruction given on that library.

Comment: Try a lot to fix the problem but can't. Still Same problem. Please help me to debug the problem. We can talk in teamviewer if you have time. Please help. Mail me at ncit.cosmos2012@gmail.com

Comment: the thing is you are trying to access it via mobile by typing the IP i.e `http://192.168.100.3/api/`, but while you try to open this URL with IP address are you connected to the same network as your computer is? can you access `192.168.100.3`?

Comment: Yeah, i can access the api through the mobile. I am connected with same network. I also try it on ARC(Advance Rest Client) replacing IP with localhost also cause same error (404 not found). http://localhost/api/oauth2/token or http://localhost/dashboard/api/oauth2/token

Comment: hmm, give me sometime will reach home and then look into it

Comment: Your rules provide that POST is used, do you have a POST request?

Comment: Yes. I have checked it with POST method. Nothing happen. Get same error (404 not found)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the repo you are using is not maintained anymore see this [**`ISSUE`**](https://github.com/Filsh/yii2-oauth2-server/issues/133) so there is no use of integrating a library whose owner has abandoned it and not active because of no update in code from last 1 year.

I would recommend you use an alternative to this repo [**`borodulin/yii2-oauth2-server`**](https://github.com/borodulin/yii2-oauth2-server) as there are people who are trying to implement same solutions and thery are diverting from Flish to the alternative repo I mentioned see here [**`ISSUE`**](https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit/issues/576)